# Does PC version of Civ-5 on Steam entitle me to Mac version?

Tags: steam, civilization-5, steam-play

I'm wondering, since my PC version of Civ-5 is registered on Steam, am I going to be able to download the Mac version when it comes out?

I switched to Mac a couple years ago, so my Mac is faster and my preferred platform now. I resurrected my old PC laptop which just barely meets minimums just to play Civ.

Comment: Long overdue update: I was in fact able to get the Mac version with my PC license.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can tell by the SteamPlay logo. The SteamPlay logo means that a game is playable on both Mac and PC, and just a Windows logo means it's only playable on Windows.

This is the SteamPlay logo: [image: SteamPlay]

This is the Windows only logo: [image: Windows]

[image: Now available on Mac]

In other words, yes.

Answer (score 2):

If Civ 5 will be part of the Steam Play program, then, Yes you will be able to download the Mac version when it releases. (this is further reinforced by the experiences from Civ4)